# python sending a hex string to serial port

Tags: python, serial-port, hex

I am trying to send a hexadecimal string to a serial port 
and it has to be in the following format '\x02\x81....' 
this is my code

```
from binascii import unhexlify
string='0281E1B1'
print unhexlify(string)
```

gives me  some randon symbols ?a+ instead of \x02\x81\xE1\xB1
I have python 2.7 so decode('hex') isnt working either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are doing it right .... you just need to send it over the port

```
print repr(unhexlify(my_string))

my_serial.write(unhexlify(my_string))

#or 

my_serial.write(my_string.decode("hex"))
```

the problem is you cant just print random bytes( `"\x##"`) to the terminal and expect to see something that makes sense ...the terminal displays characters it cannot decode a ? or like a diamond with a question mark

```
>>> '0281E1B1'.decode("hex")
'\x02\x81\xe1\xb1'
>>> print '0281E1B1'.decode("hex")
☻üß▒
>>> '0281E1B1'.decode("hex") == unhexlify('0281E1B1')
True
```

although for whatever weird reason my terminal didnt add any ? to that particular string

Comment: Thanks for explaining! You are right it all works now :)